# Don't show Intent after first load application

Tags: android

If you can help me I will be very grateful,

i want to launch an intent only in first load of my android application and save same settings. To save my settings I use `SharedPreferences`  :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit= preferences.edit();

edit.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
edit.commit();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your question ? Please explain.

Comment: I want to launch an intent only in first load of my android application

First load : intent  A -> intent B -> intent  C
Seconde load : intent  A ->intent  C

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit= preferences.edit();
if(preferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)){
        edit.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
        edit.commit();
        //Do your stuff for first Run
}else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity A, you should check in your shared preference like:

```
if(!pref.getBoolean("isFirstRun", false)){
    //Load activity B
    // put your code for updating shared pref as you mention above.
}else{
   //Load activity C
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. the default value should be true, since the first time it will load the default value